# Use Variables of functions in other.c files with Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, stm32

I'm trying to use a function von my Messung.c file in my Main.c.
I made a Messung.h with:

```
#ifndef MESSUNG_H_
#define MESSUNG_H_

void phMessung(double , double* , double* );
void tempMessung(double*);

#endif /* MESSUNG_H_ */
```

in my source file there is the function:

```
#include "Messung.h"

void phMessung(double tempWert, double *phWert,double *avin)
{
    AD7793_SetExcitDirection(AD7793_DIR_IEXC1_IOUT2_IEXC2_IOUT1);
    AD7793_SetChannel(AD7793_CH_AIN1P_AIN1M);               //ph-electrode on AIN1+ and AIN1-
    unsigned long code = AD7793_ContinuousReadAvg(20);
    *avin = ((double)code/(8388608-1))*1.05;
    *phWert = 7 - (0.0455 * (273.1+tempWert) * (*avin))*(-1);
}


void tempMessung(double *tempWert){
    AD7793_SetExcitDirection(AD7793_DIR_IEXC1_IOUT1_IEXC2_IOUT2);
    AD7793_SetChannel(AD7793_CH_AIN2P_AIN2M);                                                                       //ph-electrode on AIN1+ and AIN1-

    unsigned long tcode = AD7793_ContinuousReadAvg(20);                                                         // tcode: digitales temperatursignal avg
    double tavin = (((double)tcode/(8388608))-1)*1.05;
    double r = tavin/0.000210;
    *tempWert = ((r / 1016)-1.0)/0.00385;
}
```

and in my main im trying to call it with:

```
#include "Messung.h"
#include "main.h"
....
    while (1) {
        phMessung( tempWert, &phWert, &avin);
        tempMessung(&tempWert);

        if(AD7793_Error())while(1);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    }
```

i get the error:

```
'tempWert' undeclared (first use in this function)
  105 |   tempMessung(&tempWert);
```

same for phWert and same for avin.
I'm pretty new to c but still i want to do this, so can someone please tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Is there a variable in main called tempWert?

Comment: @user253751 no, tempWert is a temperature im getting from the function tempMessung. With that tempWert, i want to use the function phMessung, since you need the temperature for the calculation. So basically i did not define anything in main, i want to get everything out of the other sourcefiles

Comment: Pointers point to variables. If you want a pointer to a variable, you have to create the variable first.

Comment: Okay, but I created that variable in the Messung.c file and want to point to that variable from the main.c file . If i create the Variable in the main.c file, it is not the same as the one in Messung.c, is it?

Comment: Do you understand that local variables only exist inside functions? When you call tempMessung it sets up a variable called tempWert inside the function call; when it returns the variable is no longer there. *That* variable tempWert is part of the function call. And you can have different variables with the same name if they're in different functions, so don't confuse yourself by giving things the same names if that is confusing to you.

Comment: I think i get your point. Lets call tempWert = t. In the Messung.c file, void tempMessung returns t. So in void phMessung i can use that t (created in the other void function) and multiply it with the other values to get phWert. Can i not get the Value of t in main.c with pointers? I hoped i could, because i didnt manage to use extern

Answer (score 1):

Local variables exist within a particular function call. If you call the function it creates the variables and when it returns they don't exist any more. If you call the function twice each call has its own local variables. It makes no sense to talk about accessing a variable inside `tempMessung` from `phMessung`, because when `phMessing` is running, `tempMessung` *isn't* running and its variables don't exist.

Also pointers do not access other variables just by existing. You can get the pointer to a variable (by using `&`) and then use this pointer to access the variable. It does not happen automatically.

However `main`'s local variables do exist at the same time as `tempMessung` (and `phMessung`), because `main` hasn't returned. `main` is still there, waiting for `tempMessung` to return. So pointers *can* be used to send information into a function call or out of it. What you want to do is create a variable in `main` to store the temperature (let's call it `temperature` because I want to emphasize that the name doesn't have to be the same). You give `tempMessung` a pointer to that variable. `tempMessung` can use the pointer to change the variable.

```
double temperature;
tempMessing(&temperature);
// That line called tempMessing and gave it a pointer to the "temperature" variable
// tempMessing stored the temperature in the place where the pointer pointed to,
// which was the temperature variable.
// So the temperature variable now contains the temperature.

double ph;
double avin;
phMessung(temperature, &ph, &avin);
// That line called phMessung and gave it the temperature (the actual number,
// not a pointer!), and a pointer to the "ph" variable, and a pointer to the "avin"
// variable, so now ph stores the ph and avin stores the analog voltage (?)
```

---

You should be aware there is another way to do this. Any function can return up to one thing as its "return value". That is written like so:

```
double tempMessung(void) { // a function with no arguments should be written as (void). In C++ this is fixed so you can write (), but this is not C++
    ...... other code goes here ......
    return ((r / 1016)-1.0)/0.00385;
}

// in main
double temperature = tempMessung();

// or even this way - if you only need to know the temperature because of phMessung
// - because this way doesn't save it in a variable
phMessung(tempMessung(), &ph, &avin);
```

---

Lastly, computers do things in the order they are told. Since it seems that you need to know the temperature to do the pH measurement, you should tell the computer to measure the temperature first, not the pH first and then the temperature.